# How to make Delphi re-save all forms?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

After a component upgrade, some of its properties are stored differently, but only the next time the form is saved. This means that when I then edit a form that was last saved while still using the previous version of the component, in the VCS my actual changes are obscured by differences that result from the component upgrade. I could split them up into separate commits, but then I need to be on the lookout for these artifacts all the time and the effects of the component upgrade would scatter across the repository's history. Instead, I would like to have these changes bundled in a single commit right after I upgraded the component.

To make this happen, I need to force Delphi to re-save (generate) all forms in a project (group) even though no changes were made in the editor, so that the only file changes will be caused by the component upgrade. So far I did not even manage to make this happen for a single form without opening it, making a change and reverting it - the IDE seems to minimize writing to disk; just Save All without touching all units doesn't cut it. In the end I need to do it for as many forms at once as possible and opening them all in the editor isn't going to work because there are hundreds of them... I could write some AutoIt script to do everything I'd do by hand, but I hope there is some clever way that doesn't involve scripting the IDE.

Comment: @downvoter feedback appreciated

Comment: Looks like DFMCheck is what you are looking for: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck/

Comment: There is no way to do this except perhaps for if you wrote an IDE expert. That would be better than trying to use GUI automation tools. DFMCheck may help you identify dfms that are invalid but it does NOT fix them.  You could perhaps figure out how to do this programmatically inside an expert if you learned how to write IDE Experts.

Comment: I have done some very specific .DFM meta-search-replace tasks by writing Python scripts that found certain problematic elements and removed the broken elements, and inserted a few minimal missing elements.  That is probably a better idea than the expert, but you would have to make some rules like "For Entity with class X, translate A, B, and C to D, E, and F" only. In my case it had to do with form inheritance.

Comment: @WarrenP DFMCheck is not limited to checking for broken DFMs. It also has a "Open/Close all forms" feature that I use myself to synchronize the DFMs with component changes.

Comment: @UweRaabe This comes a long way indeed. Too bad I still need to confirm saving for every form separately. Otherwise it's perfect.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen Thanks a bunch for this tool! Any way to configure it not to ask for confirmation? (Otherwise I'd have to AutoIt this last bit, but that's relatively minor.)

Comment: @ThijsvanDien a new version with a "Yes To All" button and a taskbar progress bar is coming.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien The new version is released: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck/

Comment: @AndreasHausladen Great! Thanks a lot. One thing I noticed though is that opening/closing all forms through DfmCheck does not give exactly the same result as opening the form manually and hitting save. If I first save manually and then run DfmCheck again, that doesn't result in additional changes. But first DfmCheck and then manually does. More properties get cleaned up for example. Perhaps DfmCheck is trying to be too fast? It's rather confusing, since DfmCheck appears to do the same thing as what I do by hand. Unfortunate, because this way I still have some meaningless changes later on.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien DFMCheck uses ActionServices.OpenFile(), ModuleServices.FindModule() and Module.SaveFile(False, True).  So there is nothing special about it. But I found an Application.ProcessMessages after every SaveFile call, that I don't know why I've added it 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Just to remove this question from a list of unanswered questions)*

Use DFMCheck, as Andreas Hausladen says in comments:

http://idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck (originally was at http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck)

Comment: Since no-one else wants to take the credit, here you go.

Comment: The home of DFMCheck has moved:  https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck/